# SelectObject WinApi function Cannot Compiling in Rad Studio Seatle

Tags: winapi, c++builder, c++builder-10-seattle

I'm trying to compile the [below code snippet](http://www.functionx.com/bcb/gdi/rectangle.htm) in Rad Studio Seatle CBuilder 10.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    HPEN hpen, hpenOld;
    HBRUSH hbrush, hbrushOld;
    HDC hdc = this->Canvas->Handle;

    // Red pen for the border
    hpen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(255, 0, 0));
    // Blue brush for the interior.
    hbrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 255));

    // Select the new pen and brush then draw a rectangle.
    hpenOld = SelectObject(hdc, hpen);
    hbrushOld = SelectObject(hdc, hbrush);
    Rectangle(hdc, 100,100, 400,250);

    // After using your objects, delete them and restore the originals
    SelectObject(hdc, hpenOld);
    DeleteObject(hpen);
    SelectObject(hdc, hbrushOld);
    DeleteObject(hbrush);
}
```

But cannot compiling that line and showing error message.

```
hpenOld = SelectObject(hdc, hpen);
```

> [bcc32 Error] Unit1.cpp(132): E2034 Cannot convert 'void *' to 'HPEN__
>   *'   Full parser context
>       Unit1.cpp(121): parsing: void _fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *)

I can compile successfully this source code in "c++ builder 6".

Also I've checked SelectObject function declaration in CBuilder 6 and Cbuilder 10

**CBuilder 6 Declaration(wingdi.h)**

```
WINGDIAPI HGDIOBJ WINAPI SelectObject(IN HDC, IN HGDIOBJ);
```

**CBuilder 10 Declaration(wingdi.h)**

```
WINGDIAPI HGDIOBJ WINAPI SelectObject(_In_ HDC hdc, _In_ HGDIOBJ h);
```

I don't seen any different.

What's my problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SelectObject` returns `HGDIOBJ` which is not compatible with `HPEN`. The point is that `SelectObject` can return a variety of different GDI object types. It's up to you to know what type is returned, and cast accordingly. For instance:

```
hpenOld = (HPEN)SelectObject(hdc, hpen);
```

You'll need to do likewise for the other call to `SelectObject`.

Comment: FYI, this error only happens when `STRICT` is defined, where `HPEN` is defined as a pointer to a distinct `HPEN__` struct type. When `STRICT` is not defined, both `HGDIOBJ` and `HPEN` are defined as `void*` and thus assignment-compatible without casting. `STRICT` is enabled by default in C++Builder 2009+: [C++ Applications Use STRICT Type Checking](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/C%2B%2B_Applications_Use_STRICT_Type_Checking)